# Was bedeutet das Pronomen "es"?

Tags: meaning

> Was kochst du, wenn es gesund sein soll?
>
> Wenn es schnell gehen muss, gibt es auch mal eine Pizza.

Und was bedeutet übrigens *auch mal* hier?

Ich hab in einem Wörterbuch gesucht und finde, dass es *once in a while* bedeutet.

Ist das so richtig?

Comment: *auch mal* kann *once in a while* bedeuten. Hier kann man auch sagen *schon mal* im Sinne von "es kann vorkommen, dass es mal Pizza gibt".

Comment: In English und Deutsch gibt *es* ("it") dieses Wort mit ganz ähnliche Bedeutung, aber in anderen Sprachen ist *es* nicht unbedingt so. Z.b. ist *es* auch möglich, daß eigentlich nichts im zweiten Beispielsatz benützt wird, und der (Neben)satz bleibt ohne Subjekt. Die Frage ist keine einfache wörterbüchliche Übersetzung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Was kochst du, wenn es gesund sein soll"? kann mit "What do you cook if it (the food) shall be something healthy." übersetzt werden, "es" bezieht sich hier auf die Speise, also das Ergebnis des Kochens.

Eine wortwörtliche Übersetzung von "Was kochst du, wenn es schnell gehen soll?" ins Englische ist natürlich unangebracht, sie könnte aber lauten: "What do you cook, if it (i.e. the action of cooking) has to take place quickly?", "es" bezieht sich also auf die Tätigkeit des Kochens.

Das Gleiche gilt für "Wenn es schnell gehen muss, ..."

"Es gibt Pizza (zum Abendessen)." kann mit "There is pizza (for dinner)." übersetzt werden, ganz allgemein ist "es gibt" die deutsche Variante des englischen "there is", das Pronomen hat keine besondere Bedeutung, es ist einfach Teil dieser Redewendung.

Die Übersetzung "once in a while" für "auch mal" ist korrekt.

Comment: Das "es" im ersten Satz bezieht sich nicht zwangsläufig auf die Speise. Das ist eine valide Interpretation, aber man kann das "es" andererseits auch auf dieselbe Weise interpretieren wie in den anderen Sätzen. Das wird insbesondere deutlich, wenn man den Satz in einen entsprechenden Kontext setzt: "Heute wird es gesund. Und was kocht man, wenn es gesund sein soll? Möhrchen!"

Answer (score 2):

Normalerweise, meint es. "it."

> Was kochst du, wenn es gesund sein soll? What do you cook when *it* [what you cook] should be healthy?

Aber die Verbindung "es gibt" ist übersetzt "there is," nicht "it gives."

> Wenn... gibt es eine Pizza. If [condition], there is a pizza.

The second usage seems to be causing the confusion.